# Таблица через Bootstrap (spring)

Tags: java, веб-программирование, bootstrap, spring

Я написал проект который выводит таблицу, я через бутстрап сделал кнопки, а как можно сделать через бутстрап красивую таблицу. Я посмотрел примеры использовал но не выходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>All Users</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addStudent">Add Student</a>
        <br>
        <h3>List of all Students</h3>
        ${message}
        <br>
        <br>
        <table border="1px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Surname</th>


                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <c:forEach var="student" items="${studentList}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${student.name}</td>
                        <td>${student.surname}</td>


                        <td><a
                            href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editStudent/${student.id}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                        <td><a
                            href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteStudent/${student.id}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>


        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: А причем тут теги `Java` и, тем более, `Spring`???

Comment: просто проект спринг) знаю тупанул сорри)

Comment: Добавьте класс table к тегу <table>

Comment: `<table class="table">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю на сколько красиво (наляпал абы было быстро), но у меня, к примеру так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<table class="table" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="3%" style="vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center;"><small>№</small></th>
            <th width="21%" style="vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center;"><small>Наименование доп. работы</small></th>
            <th width="7%" style="vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center;"><small>Чел.-дн.</small></th>
            <th width="11%" style="vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center;"><small>Должность</small></th>
            <th width="10%" style="vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center;"><small>Постфикс</small></th>
            <th width="5%" style="vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center;"><small>Тр. разр.</small></th>
            <th width="5%" style="vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center;"><small>Доля, %</small></th>
            <th width="6%" style="vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center;"><small>Удалить должность</small></th>
            <th width="5%" style="vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center;"><small>Ср. тр. разряд</small></th>
            <th width="5%" style="vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center;"><small>Тр. коэф.</small></th>
            <th width="10%" style="vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center;"><small>Стоимость работы</small></th>
            <th width="6%" style="vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center;"><small>Добавить должность</small></th>
            <th width="6%" style="vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center;"><small>Удалить работу</small></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


<!-- цикл по значениям в группе -->
<c:forEach items="${laborCosts.extraWork}" var="eWork">
    <c:forEach items="${eWork.positionShares}" var="value" varStatus="counter">

        <tr <c:if test="${counter.last}">style="border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd"</c:if>>

            <c:if test="${counter.first}">

                <td class="data-rowspan" rowspan="${eWork.sizeShares}" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;">
                    <c:out value="${eWork.positionNumber}"></c:out>
                </td>
                <td rowspan="${eWork.sizeShares}" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd; word-wrap:break-word;">
                    <a href="#" class="job-title-editable" data-type="textarea" data-pk="${eWork.id}" data-name="jobTitle"><c:out value="${eWork.jobTitle}"></c:out></a>
                </td>

            </c:if>


            <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
                <a href="#" class="editable labor-intensity-editable" data-type="text" data-pk="${value.id}" data-name="laborIntensity"><fmt:formatNumber maxFractionDigits="6" type="number" value="${value.laborIntensity}"/></a>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: left;">
                <a href="#" class="editable position-editable" data-type="select" data-pk="${value.id}" data-value="${value.tariffCategory.id}" data-name="position"></a>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
                <a href="#" class="editable postfix-editable" data-type="text" data-pk="${value.id}" data-name="postfix"><c:out value="${value.postfix}"></c:out></a>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;"><fmt:formatNumber maxFractionDigits="6" type="number" value="${value.tariffCategory.tariffCharge}"/></td>

            <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;"><fmt:formatNumber maxFractionDigits="6" type="number" value="${value.shareOfParticipation}"/></td>
            <td valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" tabindex="-1" <c:if test="${eWork.sizeShares < 2}">disabled="disabled"</c:if> onclick="deletePosition(${value.id})">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </td>


            <c:if test="${counter.first}">

                <td rowspan="${eWork.sizeShares}" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;"><fmt:formatNumber maxFractionDigits="6" type="number" value="${eWork.averageRateCharge}"/></td>
                <td rowspan="${eWork.sizeShares}" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;"><fmt:formatNumber maxFractionDigits="6" type="number" value="${eWork.tariffCoefficient}"/></td>
                <td rowspan="${eWork.sizeShares}" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;"><fmt:formatNumber maxFractionDigits="6" type="number" value="${eWork.costOfWork}"/></td>
                <td rowspan="${eWork.sizeShares}" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" style="width: 100%" onclick="addNewPosition(${eWork.id})">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td rowspan="${eWork.sizeShares}" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" tabindex="-1" style="width: 100%" onclick="deleteAdditionalWork(${eWork.id})">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                </td>

            </c:if>

        </tr>

    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="10" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: right;">
                Итого:
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
                <b><fmt:formatNumber maxFractionDigits="6" type="number" value="${laborCosts.cost}"/></b>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;"></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>



</table>
```

Comment: А она будет у меня работать? просто она у меня связано с базой данных)

Comment: Нет, она работает с моей БД - я про то, что подгоняйте стилями всё что вам не нравится.

Comment: Спасибо вам))))

Comment: А можете помочь с нуля обычную таблицу написать красивую, просто я только начинаю изучать и я в вашем коде запутался немного

Comment: Посмотрите комментарий от @not a Programmer, на том же сайте бутстрапа  есть примеры: http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.6/docs/css/#tables 
Копируете от туда, запускаете, смотрите.
Всё сводиться к тому, что вам нужно посмотреть как делать таблицу
Как делать таблицу: http://htmlbook.ru/html/table
А дальше запихнуть в неё бутстраповские классы.